# Has Iran presented any evidence that their drones (used in Ukraine) were sent to Russia before the war?

Tags: russian-federation, ukraine, military, iran, foreign-aid

It seems Iran initially denied they sent drones to Russia, but later Iran’s foreign minister Hossein Amirabdollahian [said](https://edition.cnn.com/2022/11/05/middleeast/iran-drones-russia-intl/index.html) that they sent some, but before the war.

> “Some western countries have accused Iran of helping the war in Ukraine by providing drones and missiles to Russia. The part regarding missiles is completely wrong. The part about drones is correct, we did provide a limited number of drones to Russia in the months before the start of the war in Ukraine,” Amirabdollahian told reporters in Tehran.

**Did Iran then or later present any evidence to back up their version of events**?

Certainly the massed drone attacks were not noticed by the Western press until some months into the war, probably [in October](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-63921007). According to [one Italian source](https://www.ispionline.it/en/publication/assessing-russian-use-iranian-drones-ukraine-facts-and-implications-36520), Ukraine only downed the first such [Iranian-designed] drone in September, i.e. 6 months after the February invasion. There's also been [talk](https://www.wsj.com/articles/moscow-tehran-advance-plans-for-iranian-designed-drone-facility-in-russia-11675609087) of establishing a factory in Russia, but the Western press only said something about a survey team in Jan 2023. So, does Iran claim that or another licensed factory is or was already operational and responsible for most of the Iranian-design drones seen over Ukraine? Or do they claim Russia just massively stockpiled the drones it received before the war?

Comment: I recall a lot of news about these drones in the late fall 2022. Are they still actively used in significant numbers? I don't recall any news about drone use for the last 2 months or so.

Comment: The UK Defence Intelligence briefing recently wrote that apartently the drones are not used anymore and they believe Russia just run out of drones, see https://twitter.com/DefenceHQ/status/1629374055152332801

Comment: @quarague: according to ISW they've got a new batch https://www.understandingwar.org/backgrounder/russian-offensive-campaign-assessment-april-21-2023

Comment: @quarague: and apparently they were holding back for V-day celebrations [for which they launched 60 drones in one attack on Kyiv, described as the "biggest" so far] https://www.reuters.com/world/europe/least-five-wounded-due-russian-strikes-kyiv-city-officials-say-2023-05-07/ (One could joke: V-bombs for V-day.)

Comment: @quarague: and the factory is on-line now https://isis-online.org/isis-reports/detail/visible-progress-at-russias-shahed-drone-production-site and producing effects https://www.euronews.com/2023/11/25/russia-launches-biggest-drone-attack-on-kyiv-since-start-of-the-war I guess that kinda answers the question.